# What is numpy version 0x...?

Tags: numpy

My Python code fails with the following error:

```json
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe
```

How do you translate `0x10` and `0xe` in numpy versions? I currently have numpy `1.21.0`, so I suppose `1.21.0` == `0xe`, but how do I translate `0x10` in semantic versioning?

Comment: the "API version" it's referencing I think will be the C API version, not the Python package version, so there may not be a 1:1 mapping between them. 0xe is 14, 0x10 is 16 -- you can see the mappings here in the numpy source where they helpfully list the appropriate numpy package version: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/setup_common.py#L35
so you need to go to 1.23 or above, I think

Comment: Sounds like you nailed it. Please post your comment as an answer and I’ll accept it!